# How to avoid narrowing conversion with floating point literals inside template functions

Tags: c++, floating-point

What do you usually do with floating point literals inside template functions?

Suppose that we have the following code:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    T bar;
};

template <typename T>
void foo(T val)
{
    Foo<T> instance = { val * 5.0 };
}

int main()
{
    foo(0.0f);
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b159117097cc2461

It gives me the following warning / error (depending on the compiler / flags):

```
narrowing conversion of '(((double)val) * 5.0e+0)' from 'double' to 'float' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
     Foo<T> instance = { val * 5.0 };
```

How is it usually avoided? Should I just wrap any floating point literal in `T(0.0)` like:

```
Foo<T> instance = { val * T(5.0) };
```

Or is there any more elegant solution?

Comment: Sounds about right, what's not to like with writing the conversion?

Comment: @Passer By Dunno. Just wondering what others usually do in such cases

Comment: Well, your other option to write it with a float literal. Now the conversion is not *narrowing* if it happens.

Comment: That sounds opinion-based: you don't have a clear problem statement and is asking what people do that is more "elegant"

Comment: @StoryTeller Until you use some integral type :)

Comment: @PasserBy - This whole premise is wrong if that function isn't meant to be called with floating point types only. What is `T(0.5)` supposed to be then?

Comment: @StoryTeller It would then be a bug to have a conversion on the operand rather than the product. `val * 5.0`, the original expression, still makes sense if it's an `int`

Comment: @PasserBy - Is it a bug? The OP states it solves their problem, and they just worry about style. I'd like to think the OP wouldn't ponder a solution that's flat out wrong on their simplest use cases.

Comment: @StoryTeller You're probably right

Comment: umm, if the live snippet is compiled in c++14 as it seems, how can be a warning and not an error as it should be ?!

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes - The same way [this is compiled with but a warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07aa70b33e2f5453). `-pedantic` only emits those issues as warnings, despite closely adhering to the specification.

Comment: @Storyteller, do you mean g++ treats narrowing conversions with bracket-init as a language extension ? ( clang does not, as far as I can tell ) what's the rationale ?

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes - I wouldn't know. Perhaps they had some worries about breaking code that uses GNU extensions? I can only speculate.

Comment: In your snippet, replace `5.0` by `5`: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec0416af231a5a13).

Comment: Why not just cast the literal?

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that `T(5.0)` is the most elegant solution. If `T` is a `double` then the conversion should be ignored by the compiler to which it is the same as writing `5.0`. If `T` is a `float` then the conversion should resolved at compile time being equivalent writing as a float literal `5.0f`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only dealing with a small number of well-defined magic constants but you need full control over the value of those constants for all possible `T`s, it might make sense moving them to a traits class:

```
template<typename T>
struct FooTraits;

template<>
struct FooTraits<float> { static constexpr float magicN() { return 5.0f; } };

template<>
struct FooTraits<double> { static constexpr double magicN() { return 5.0; } };

template <typename T>
void foo(T val)
{
     Foo<T> instance = { val * FooTraits<T>::magicN() };
}
```

This is some significant overhead in terms of boilerplate, so only do this if you actually need the added flexibility. If a simple cast to `T` works for all your use cases, there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

> How is it usually avoided?

I don’t think you should ‘avoid’ it as such, I’d say it depends on the final function semantics.

That is, if you want to disallow narrowing you use `{}` and let the compilation fail ( at least, as of >=c++11 );
if you want to allow narrowing to T on the *final* result you write `instance = T( val * 5.0 )` and let converions do the rest for each possible T;
if you want to allow narrowing to T in *intermidiate* results or constants you wrap in `T()` there;
if you want the user to decide, you add a trait/policy class performing the final/intermidiate conversions …

that said, on one thing I'm sure: as a user of your function, I'd be very uncomfortable if any of the possibilities above were undocumented, or unreasonable given the function ultimate goal...

BTW, if you're question focuses only on constants, then I'd follow [boost approach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/math/doc/html/constants.html), maybe with the aid of c++14's variable templates.